# Change application physical path from web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a site hosted in IIS (Default Web Site) 10 with several sub directories that have been converted to applications. In the application hosts.config file the physical path for the website is being set when I open up the solution from a branch (Dev branch).  However the applications under the default website are not having their physical paths updated.  I am trying to figure out how to set their physical paths to the current directory.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: That’s impossible. That must be set in applicationHost.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to solve my issue, though not through the web.config. I had all the projects that were applications under the same website set to "Use External Host" in the project properties.  I swapped this setting to use Local IIS on all the projects and closed visual studio and re-opened and it was back to updating the physical paths on load.